# Meaning of exclamation/question mark before UML method name

Tags: uml, class-diagram

My teacher uses exclamation marks and question marks before method names in UML class diagrams to distinguish between *commands* (`!`) and *queries* (`?`):

[image: UML Class Diagram]

As I've never seen this before, I wonder whether it's actually used in practice or not and what the actual meaning is.

Basically, *commands* are methods that don't have a return type whereas *queries* are methods that do have, so I consider these symbols to be redundant. Moreover I couldn't find anything about this notation on the internet.

I'd really appreciate a clarification.

Comment: Separating queries and commands does make sense (https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CommandQuerySeparation.html) but I don't think that it is "official" UML notation. Don't expect people outside of your class/school to know this notation.

Comment: @AnnaVopureta Thanks for the article!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is no official notation. Besides the fact that prefixing things which are obvious through their signature is pointless, it will just confuse readers which are not familiar with that kind of notation.

Comment: Okay, that's the answer I expected. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

As remarked by Anna Vopureta and Thomas Kilian, the notation used by your teacher is not standard UML. But as pointed out in the article of Martin Fowler recommended by Anna Vopureta, and missing in the asnwer of Thomas Kilian, it makes sense to distinguish between those operations/methods with return value that represent pure queries (not changing the state) and those that do not (due to state changes).

So, we have to deal with three cases:

1. operations/methods without return value
2. operations/methods with return value

   1. changing the state
   2. not changing the state (pure queries)

A pure query method can be expressed in a UML class diagram by appending the operation property `query` in curly braces to the operation declaration.

In your example the correct operation declarations would be

```
+foo()
+bar1(): int
+bar2(): int {query}
```